# RoR: How can I indent one input form but not the other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

so I am trying to indent the form given by this code.

```
<%= form_for([micropost, micropost.comments.build]) do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
      <p2>Who are you?</p2>
      <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <p2>What deal are you offering?</p2>
      <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Submit"%>
    </div>
```

Now my css file has this

```
/* forms */

input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
```

and I could just add something like margin-left: 80px;
but this would indent all of my input forms. How can I perhaps name this form differently so that I can talk to it with my css file? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using google chrome I would highly suggest using stylebot to test your css modifications in real time. SO helpful. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha

Also, what you need to do is add a unique id to the form or form element you wish to change.

For the whole form

```
<%= form_for([micropost, micropost.comments.build], :html => { :id => "blah_form" }) do |f| %>
```

For just one field

```
<%= f.text_area :body, :id => 'blah_field' %>
```

For further info on form_for:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Comment: ok well that doesnt give me an error, but it doesnt indent the form. I put in my css file. blah form {margin-left:80px;} should I be calling it differently?

Comment: well, in your css you need to put #blah_form input {margin-left:80px}

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= form_for([micropost, micropost.comments.build], :html => {:id => "some_id" }) do |f| %>
```

This add an unique id to the form so you can indent it however you want in CSS and don't change others.

I mean, to only change it, you can define something for that id in you CSS.

Comment: Yes, because you need to put the :html symbol inside of the form_for(), as suggested in my answer

Comment: sorry my bad, yes you have to put inside the form_for( )

Comment: You've got an extra ')' after build]